# Marginal Analysis and Optimization

Tags: calculus

A manufacturer estimates that when x thousand units of a particular commodity are produced each month,the total cost will be C(x)=0.4x²-3x+40 thousand dollars and all x units can be sold at a price of y=22.2-1.2x dollars per unit.

- Determine the level of production that results in maximum profit.
- What is the maximum profit?
- At what level of production is the cost minimum?
- What is the minimum cost?
- At what level of production is the average cost per unit minimized?

Any help  pls? This is for my Finals ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$TC = .4x^2-3x+40$

Marginal Cost $= .8x-3$

$TR = 22.2x - 1.2x^2$

Marginal Revenue =$ 22.2-2.4x$

Max Profit occurs when MC = MR, find x by equating both.

Althernatively, set $(\frac{d}{dx} (TC-TR) = 0$ and find x

Plug x in $(TR-TC)$ and find maximum profit

Similarly, set $(\frac{d}{dx} (TC) = 0$ and find x to find the quantity that will minimize the cost

Plug x to find the minimum cost

Similarly, find Average cost $= \frac{TC}{x}$

Set the derivative of this to 0 and find x that will the quantity that will minimize the Average cost.